# Pandas: update the information of certain row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame `df` like below:

```
name     team
Peter     A
Mary      A
John      B
```

Now I want to update John's team from B to C. I could loop over the dataframe, find the row with `name = 'John'`, delete it and add a new row. However, I am wondering is there a more elegant way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['name'] == 'John', 'team'] = 'C'
```

The resulting output:

```
    name team
0  Peter    A
1   Mary    A
2   John    C
```